# How to use Google Colab with a local TensorFlow Jupyter server using Powershell on Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to learn TensorFlow on Windows 10 using Docker, but I'm stuck at the very beginning of the environment setup.

I followed this:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install#download-a-package

And did:

> docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter

Then I followed this:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner

Problem is when I tried to connect to my local server with Google Colab (using Google Chrome), I get the following error in the docker log:

> Blocking Cross Origin API request for /http_over_websocket.  Origin:
>   https://colab.research.google.com, Host: localhost:8888

The error is very explicit and Google Colab gave me the solution right away:

> jupyter notebook \
>   --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \   --port=8888 \   --NotebookApp.port_retries=0

But, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to add this parameter to the docker image/container/command/configuration...

What I tried so far:

1. I tried passing the parameters to the docker run command but it doesn't work.
2. I tried running the container without -it and then connect to it to relaunch the server with these parameters but as soon as I stop the Jupyter server, it stops the docker.
3. I tried to specify "-u $(id -u):$(id -g)" when starting the docker, since I get a warning at the container start that I shouldn't connect as the root user... But it's not working, since I'm using PowerShell on Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, after a few hours of searching around I found out how to overwrite a docker image default CMD to append the "--NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'" and it worked!

So the solution is:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a million.  For Nvidia GPU Tensorflow support, I installed [Nvidia Driver](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-driver) with GPU support, the [Nvidia Docker Toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) then added  --gpus all, so that the final command became:  
sudo docker run -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'

Comment: For future reference, the relevant Dockerfiles can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v2.5.0/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles)